# Javascript Prototype property : Prototype based Inheritance

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I'm confused with Javascript's prototype property. 
See the below Code.

```
var s = 12;
var s1 = new String();

console.log(s.constructor);  // Outputs: Number() { [native code] } 
console.log(s instanceof String); // Outputs: false
console.log(s instanceof Object); // Outputs: false
//console.log(toString() in s);   
console.log(s.isPrototypeOf(Object)); // Outputs: false
//console.log(s.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Object));

console.log(s.hasOwnProperty ("toString")); // Outputs: false

console.log(s.toString()); // // Outputs: 12
// My Question is how does toString() function is been called, where does it falls int the prototype chain. Why is it not showing undefined.

console.log(s1.constructor); // Outputs: Number() { [native code] } 
console.log(s1 instanceof String); // Outputs: true
```

I understand that when we create an object by using {} or constructor (new String()) above, it inherits from Object.prototype. And thats why `console.log(s1 instanceof String); // Outputs: true` and thus we're able to call toString() on s1. But i'm confused with what happens in the case of `var x = "someString" or var x = something.`

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between string primitive values (like `"hello world"`) and String objects. Primitive types — strings, numbers, booleans — are not objects.

When primitive values are *used* like objects, with the `.` or `[]` operators, the runtime implicitly wraps the values in objects via  the corresponding constructors (`String`, `Number`, `Boolean`). Primitive values don't have properties, but because of that automatic wrapping you can do things like

```
var n = "hello world".length;
```

and it works.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now, Just one more question, Is it correct if I say premitive types don't have prototype property or no property at all, it's just the implicit conversion that allows them to call the desired property if applicable.

Comment: @nitte93user3232918 yes that's correct - primitive values are not objects, so they have none of the things objects have (like a prototype).